# How to avoid foreign-key-constraint violations using pure JPA/Hibernate annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, foreign-keys, hsqldb

I'm working on a problem with my database-model for a while now. I use **Hibernate** to manage my entities and the whole thing is stored in a **HSQLDB (In memory database)**, so the tables are created at runtime by hibernate. A short example of my annotated classes looks like follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Paper")
public class Paper {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "Paper_Ref", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SrcID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DstID") })
  private Set<Paper> references = new HashSet<Paper>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Paper_Ref")
public class PaperRef
{
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "SrcID")
  private Long srcId;

  @Column(name = "DstID")
  private Long dstId;
}
```

As you can see, one paper links to several other papers and the corresponding relation is stored in a table called Paper_Ref. SrcID and DstID have a foreign-key-nature to primary-key of Paper. But the addressed primary-keys don't necessarily exist in my database.

The whole thing works fine, but if there is some inconsistency in the data (e.g. adding a paper-reference before adding the corresponding papers) I get a foreign-key-constraint violation. Furthermore I'm not really able to control these inconsistencies manually because I receive the data from another source that doesn't have any constraints.

Usually that's how everybody would expect the relationship to work, but i'm searching for a way to avoid the violation or just ignore it. For example by manually removing the constraint.

My own workaround is to form a native query, that looks like:

```
SELECT p FROM Paper AS p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT pr.dstId FROM PaperRef pr WHERE srcId = :id)
```

But preferrably I want to use a native hibernate-solution where I can call the getter for my Set of papers, without using a selfmade query.

Is there any way to remove/disable the foreign-key constraint or another way to work around  this beahviour? Or is it a misunderstanding of mine how the relations in hibernate work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you inserting Papers at the same time you insert Paper-Refs?

Comment: What is `PaperRef` for? Hibernate is able to create the join table by itself.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Not at the same time, but I would like to insert paper-refs before the affected papers (As said, I get the data from external sources). Thomas I get this format by the external service. No way to manipulate it. SrcID and DstID are both foreign-keys to id in Paper.

Comment: But than there is something wrong. Store the paper-refs with yet not received papers somewhere else and then insert them when the papers have been imported.

Comment: Yeah I know it sounds weird. There are even Paper-Refs in the external service that will never have a real Paper-entity, even if they refer to some sort of primary key. The external service is missing some of the papers for a reason I don't know. So I simply want to get the things I can get and leave the rest alone, as there were no foreign keys. The database is immediately cleared after I did some operations and it is only used for that single purpose. Naturally you would never ever think of turning the constraint-check off, but in my special situation it's a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think I did now solve the problem. Thanks to all readers and contributors. **HSQLDB** provides an option to disable foreign-key-checks at runtime. The SQL-statement is as follows:

```
SET DATABASE REFERENTIAL INTEGRITY FALSE;
```

Turning off this feature has another consequence which is also noted in the [HSQLDB Docs](http://hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html#set_refint-section). Hibernate doesn't keep track of the changes made at the database anymore, so without further actions incomplete results are returned for the relationships (Subselects). To fix this, `EntityManager.refresh()` has to be called for *every object* that is probably detached!

I just use the in-memory database to get join-functionality, as the external service doesn't provide such a feature. I remove the entities afterwards, so it's not a big drawback for me.

Happy coding!

Comment: But that will affect the whole database, which might have negative effects on other parts of the application.